# lodash filtering nested json

Tags: node.js, lodash

Hi I have the following json data...

```
    {
    "contacts":
    [
        {
            "contactId": "00001",
            "firstName": "test",
            "lastName": "test",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "phone": "0207 0000000",
            "role": "Surveyor",
            "customer": "00001",
            "projects": [{"projId": "00002"}]
        },
        {
            "contactId": "00002",
            "firstName": "test1",
            "lastName": "test1",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "phone": "0207 1111111",
            "role": "Manager",
            "customer": "00001",
            "projects": [{"projId": "00002"}, {"projId": "00003"}]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need an API endpoint that returns contacts based on projID but am having problems because the projId is nested in the projects array...

```
    //Get contacts by Project
app.get('/v1/projcontacts/:id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    var projContacts = lodash.filter(contactData.contacts, { 'projId': id });
    res.json(projContacts);
})
```

Anyone help me out with the code above to get lodash to look inside projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lodash may be overkill for this. You could use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which has the added benefit of exiting early when it finds the first match:

```
app.get('/v1/projcontacts/:id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    var projContacts = contactData.contacts.filter(contact => {
        return contact.projects.some(project => project.projId === id);
    });
    res.json(projContacts);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Nice alternative to using Lodash. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
app.get('/v1/projcontacts/:id', function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  var projContacts = contacts.filter(
    contact => contact.projects.map(
      projects => projects.projId === id
    ).includes(true)
  )
  res.json(projContacts);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

---

```js
const data = {
    "contacts":
    [
        {
            "contactId": "00001",
            "firstName": "test",
            "lastName": "test",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "phone": "0207 0000000",
            "role": "Surveyor",
            "customer": "00001",
            "projects": [{"projId": "00002"}]
        },
        {
            "contactId": "00002",
            "firstName": "test1",
            "lastName": "test1",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "phone": "0207 1111111",
            "role": "Manager",
            "customer": "00001",
            "projects": [{"projId": "00002"}, {"projId": "00003"}]
        }
    ]
};

const projId = "00003";

// E.g Filter by project ID "00003"
const results = data.contacts.filter(x => x.projects.some(x => x.projId === projId));

console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4));
```